# Demo Code for Detectron Not Detecting Object Instances

Tags: computer-vision, detectron

I am trying to get the demo code for [Detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) working locally on my laptop. Everything appears to run correctly, but no object instances are detected, even when I use the image from the Colab demo.

I am running on a non-GPU Mac. I followed the [installation instructions](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html) to install Detectron. I have the following module versions on my machine:

- detectron2@git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@ea3b3f22bf1de58008599794f149149ff65d3780
- opencv-python==4.5.3.56
- torch==1.9.0
- torchvision==0.10.0

I copied demo.py, predictor.py, mask_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml, and Base-RCNN-FPN.yaml from Detectron's github. I then ran [inference demo with pretrained model command](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/getting_started.html). The specific command was this:

```
python demo.py --input 000000439715.jpeg --output output --config-file mask_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml --opts MODEL.WEIGHTS detectron2://COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl MODEL.DEVICE cpu
```

000000439715.jpeg is the sample image of the man on horseback from the [Colab notebook demo](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16jcaJoc6bCFAQ96jDe2HwtXj7BMD_-m5). The last line of the output is

```
000000439715.jpeg: detected 0 instances in 6.77s
```

The image in the output directory has no annotation on it.

The logging output looks okay to me. The only thing that may be an indication of a problem is a warning at the top

```
[08/28 12:35:18 detectron2]: Arguments: Namespace(confidence_threshold=0.5, config_file='mask_rcnn_R_101_FPN_3x.yaml', input=['000000439715.jpeg'], opts=['MODEL.WEIGHTS', 'detectron2://COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl', 'MODEL.DEVICE', 'cpu'], output='output', video_input=None, webcam=False)
[08/28 12:35:18 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: [Checkpointer] Loading from detectron2://COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/137849600/model_final_f10217.pkl ...
[08/28 12:35:18 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: Reading a file from 'Detectron2 Model Zoo'
WARNING [08/28 12:35:19 fvcore.common.checkpoint]: Some model parameters or buffers are not found in the checkpoint:
```

I'm not sure what to do about it though.

I tried not specifying the model weights. I also tried setting the confidence threshold to zero. I got the same results.

Am I doing something wrong? What are the next debugging steps?

Comment: I have the same problem, Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question with you, just like:

```
 WARNING [xxxxxxxxx fvcore.common.checkpoint]: Some model parameters or buffers are not found in the checkpoint:
```

and this warning made my result very bad. Finally I found that I use a wrong weight file.
Hope this can help you.